# Can't enable wireless again after disabling it by accident on linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, networking

My Acer notebook has a button that can disable the wireless network device when pressed. Since it is near the ESC key, sometimes I press it on accident, especially when editing something with Vim. When I press the wireless switch to enable the device again, nothing happens. Using the command `ifconfig wlan0 up` results in the following error:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Unknown error 132
```

Rebooting and logging on linux again didn't solve anything. I had to log into windows. The device started out disabled, then pressing the button reenabled the device. I'd like to be able either to reenable wireless at will, or outright disable the wireless switch button. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [modify the hal configuration](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-index.html) in order for the button to be recognized properly.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but its a good tip for Vim users.  If you don't use your caps lock key, you can change your caps lock key into an escape key using xmodmap. Just put the following lines in a file in your home directory called .Xmodmap

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Escape
```

Then run this to activate it:

```
xmodmap - < .Xmodmap
```

Most distributions will read that file automatically when you login to X.